# (Geometry Nodes) Instance on Points: Create Array Of One Object With Random Group Input Values

Tags: animation, modifiers, geometry-nodes, instances, random

I have created a Geometry Nodes patch, which is able to switch between multiple Objects (simple number Meshes; Range: 1-8 ; Group Input: "NUMMER") in different types (e.g. Solid Green Look, Wire Frame Look, etc. ; Range: 1-5; Group Input: "TYPE").
These two Group Inputs are Integer values.

I used this patch for animation purposes, because by this method it was pretty easy to place and replace different meshes on one position (by handling only one Object).

My next step was creating an Array out of this interchangeable Object with the Instance on Points Node (on a Grid).

You can see the whole patch I just tried to explain on this image. (The visible switches rely on the Input "TYPE", switching between Node Groups, which contain the real Object Info, relying on the Group Input "NUMMER" using the same "switching" principle as shown here)

[image: You can see the whole patch I just tried to explain on this image. (The visible switches rely on the Input "TYPE", switching between Node Groups, which contain the real Object Info, relying on the Group Input "NUMMER" using the same "switching" principle as shown here)]

What I am trying to achieve now, is to be able to manipulate the "Number Wall" shown above, to consist of random numbers, chosen between Range 1-8, which is defined by Group Input "NUMMER" . It should look like a random matrix.

Do You see any possibility to manipulate the different Instances on this Grid with a random Value in each of their Group Input ?

Or do I need to change the order of my patch to make this operation possible?

I would be pleased, if anyone could solve this!

Thank You :)